# How do I change a Themes Header Image?

Tags: images, themes, uploads, media-library

I am having trouble locating the location of my theme's header.jpg so that I can upload and replace it with a new jpeg.

The theme that is being used for my site is the "Flat-Theme" version 1.0 By the ShapeBootstrap team. When I go to "Pages" and edit my "Homepage" the header image is not present, it is also not in my site's "Media Library". Under "Page Attributes" my Homepage uses the "Frontpage" template. When I go to the appearance editor, specifically go to edit the
"Flat Theme: Frontpage Page Template (page-frontpage.php)" I see that the theme references the header.jpg image in the coding for the header. If I am on my homepage, if I right click and "View Background Image" the URL shows up as:

http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/flat-theme/img/header.jpg

I have been unable to locate how to change the header.jpg image for the URL above. Can someone please point me in the right direction!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your theme supports header images, it should be under Appearance > Header. No need to replace the old file, you can simply upload a new one. If this is not the case, you can change the reference to `header-new.jpg` in the editor, and upload your new header to the same folder via your ftp client. You could also replace the `header.jpg` file but then you would lose the default one.

The recommended solution would be to create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), but that's slightly more complicated.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to support them as I have tried that solution. I assume by uploading the header to http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/flat-theme/img/header.jpg it was a work around to that deficiency of the theme. So the only way for me would be to change that header.jpg image

Comment: You could change the reference to header-new.jpg in the editor, and simply upload your new file there, without having to replace the old image.

Comment: Sorry for the novice question, but how would I upload the header-new.jpg in the editor?

Comment: In other words, how do I upload something to the http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/flat-theme/img/...

Comment: You cannot upload it via the editor. You need to change the filename in the editor, and then upload it to your ftp account inside /wp-content/themes/flat-theme/img/

Comment: Once I download a program to do this will I need any further logins than the admin password from my website?

Comment: You need the FTP login. I don't know where you host your website, but you should have that somewhere. I can recommend filezilla as an FTP program.

Comment: If you don't have ftp access, you can also upload it via the Media Library in Wordpress, check the URL of the image there after you upload it, and then use that URL inside the editor.

Comment: When I add the new header to the media library the URL is: http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/header2.jpg  The code that references the header is: <!--<img src="img/header.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>--> would I change that to: <!--<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/header2.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>-->?  Is there any other code I have to change?

Comment: You would add src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/header2.jpg". However, if there's a "<!-- -->" around it, it means that the code is commented out, and probably you'll need to change it in a different place!

Answer (score -1):

yea you need ftp access.

Fetch > FileZilla (both are free tho.  Well, Fetch asks for registration after trial period)